# Powershell timestamp format changes in Excel

Tags: powershell, date, timestamp, append, getdate

I'm building a function which returns the date of the last 6 months, lets you choose one, and appends it to the column **Date** in the MMM/YY format. I'm using this in a GUI and it shows it like this:

[image]

Somehow it only works for the month october.. What's going wrong here??

[image]

Code I'm using:

````
$dateList=-6..0 |ForEach-Object{ (Get-Date).AddMonths($_).ToString('MMM/yy') }
$txtDateList.Items.Clear()
foreach ($textdate in $dateList) {
                      $txtDateList.Items.Add($textdate)
                      }

$txtDate = $txtDateList.SelectedItem
$sheet.cells.item($row, $colDate.Column).value = $txtDate```
````

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to check what your Excel needs when custom formatting a date cell. Mine (Dutch Excel) wants format `MMM-jj`, but more likely you need `MMM-yy`.

Insert the dates as datetime objects, when done, format the date column.

Something like this:

```
$file     = 'D:\Test\Map1.xlsx'

$today    = Get-Date
# set the reference date to be the first day of this month, 
# with time part set to 00:00:00 (midnight)
$refDate  = (Get-Date -Year $today.Year -Month $today.Month -Day 1).Date

# Build an array of dates from the reference date, so all will be on the 1st day of the month
$dateList = -6..0 | ForEach-Object{ $refDate.AddMonths($_) }

# create an Excel COM object and open the file
$excel         = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$excel.Visible = $false
$workbook      = $excel.Workbooks.Open($file)
$sheet         = $workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)

$row = 1  # starting row
$col = 1  # the column where the dates are inserted

# insert the dates
foreach ($date in $dateList) {
    # Excel will NOT regard this as Date if a formatted string is entered.
    $sheet.Cells.Item($row++, $col) = $date
}

# format the entire date column
$sheet.Columns.Item($col).EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "MMM-yy"  # This is LOCALIZED, check your Excel!

# save, close and clean-up
$workbook.Save()
$workbook.Close()
$excel.Quit()    

# clean-up used Excel COM objects
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($sheet)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($workbook)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel)
[System.GC]::Collect() 
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

Comment: Thanks! However, this script returns the complete date and time. 29-4-2020  15:40:54. I just need the date without the time and preferably the first day of the month.. How can I fix this?

Comment: @Sbirq I have added some code to have all dates start at the 1st day of the month. During testing, I found that Excel will not see a **formatted date string** as valid date and then the formatting within Excel as you would like does not work. Entering the dates as DateTime objects **does** work. We therefore cannot _remove_ the time part, but we can set it to 00:00:00 as the code now does.

Comment: Thanks Theo. I'm using the formatted date string now. It shows it correctly in Excel (feb-20, mar-20, apr-20). When I load the data into Power BI, it recognizes the date and it can be processed. Only limitation is that it somehow shows the 20th of every month instead of first day (20 feb, 20 apr). The visualizations are based on month and year though so I guess I can live with it.. thanks again

Comment: @Sbirq Sorry, I don't know PowerBI.. Seems odd that it breaks the format on the 20th though.. That is not what the code or Excel produces..

Comment: The function obtains the dates of the last 6 months and shows them in the listbox in the 'MMM-yy' format (nov-19, dec-19, jan-20). However, when I append to Excel it shows (nov-20, dec-20) and when I click on it (19-11-2020, 19-12-2020). The only right date is the current date, then it shows (may-20 and 1-5-2020). As for the rest it shows the 20th of the month.

Comment: This only happens with COM objects though, I'm using the ImportExcel module in my script as well and it returns it like it should (first day of the month)